# Apache Tomcat Started but shows nothing in the browser

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0 in my System at work and trying to run a simple test servlet before that I installed Apache Tomcat and set the port to 9090 the I started the server.

After that when I type localhost:9090 and press enter it shows nothing in the browser, not even an error...
I have tried to run other examples through the server even tried to run some HTML files but it shows no output in the screen.
I have attached a snapshot of the problem with this.[image]

Comment: please check the logs in the "log" directory for errors. What is inside your `webapps` folder?

Comment: Do you deploy something ? what is your welcome-file-list ? what is your context root ?

Comment: I have a fresh installation of tomcat in my PC nothing is been changed just the port number is changed while installation to 9090.

Comment: It is not even showing the homepage of tomcat as you can see in the Snapshot\

Comment: My Welcome File List: <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

Comment: please check the catalina- and localhost-logs for exceptions. Are there any?

Comment: Thanks for helping everyone, but now the problem is solved actually there was another server running on that port so it was not showing any output